API4 Endpoint for external request using GET
When using API4 endpoint https://mysite/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/ajax/rest/MyExtensionEntity/get&_authx=ABC1234&_authxSiteKey=QWER1234, I get redirected to a login page by WP when not logged in. If logged in, I would get "SECURITY ALERT: Ajax requests can only be issued by javascript clients, eg. CRM.api3()." . In AuthX settings, HTTP Parameter credential include JWT, API Key.
The Entity for API4 is using AbstractEntity. I am just using get action at the moment.
The purpose of the endpoint is so external sites can get data. Is there any settings I can do allow the request.
Edit:
tried using civicrm/ajax/api4/ instead. Response is SECURITY ALERT: Ajax requests can only be issued by javascript clients, eg. CRM.api4().
Edit 2:
I also tried adding Bearer, but prompts same error

At the bottom here is a collapsed accordion with a tip: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/authx/#settings. If you do that and then it works, then it means your authx settings are the issue.

@Demerit Thank you. Will try.
